# Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set property of 'fillStyle' of null HTML5 Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, methods, typeerror

I'm playing with HTML5 canvas element with JavaScript. Now I can draw shapes to the canvas with internal JavaScript when I create an external file I get an `Uncaught Type Error`. All I want to do is draw a rectangle to my canvas through an external file.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FireBlaster</title>
</head>

<body style="background:#111111">
    <div id="inner">
        <button id="drawSquareBtn" type="button">Draw Square</button>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600px" ; height="400px;" style=" dispaly:block; background:#000000; margin:8% 25%;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
//JavaScript Document
var canvasBg = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvasBg.getContext('2D');

function drawSquare() {

    alert('your pressed a button!');
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0A0AFF";
    ctx.fillRect(200, 150, 150, 50);
}
var drawSquareBtn = document.getElementById('drawSquareBtn');
drawSquareBtn.addEventListener('click', drawSquare, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The d in `getContext("2d")` needs to be lower case.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/XMMCn/)**

```
// Changed d to lower case
var ctx = canvasBg.getContext('2d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong : -- `var ctx = canvasBg.getContext('2D');`

Right :--  `var ctx = canvasBg.getContext('2d');`

`D` capital does not create instance.